# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar"

Tags: toolbar, androidx

I am trying to run my code in which i don't use the toolbar but somehow i am getting a  java.lang.RuntimeException stating that it is unable to start the activity because it can't inflate the androidx toolbar class  here's the code:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout)getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_base,null);
       FrameLayout frameLayout=constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,frameLayout,true);
      mProgressBar =constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    }
    public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

my xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_content">

    </FrameLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here's the error that am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foodapp/com.example.foodapp.RecipeListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.foodapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:905) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:703) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.foodapp.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:15) 
        at com.example.foodapp.RecipeListActivity.onCreate(RecipeListActivity.java:27) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) ..... more
```

i tried invalidate/cache , rebuild and clean project , nothing works

Comment: im running into similar issue as well. 
tried all what you mention and also tried to build a new project in new place from version control but get the error when trying to deploy the app to a device to test. no luck so far.

Comment: i have fixed it by using 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0' , instead of version 1.4.0 , try it out

Comment: @linasaeed Thank you, working solution!